# how to handle null para in dynamic sql

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am using dynamic sql.here is my sp.I want to check for null.Which approch is good one.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[proc_insertsample]
@pname varchar(10),
@rdatetime varchar(10),
@fromcountry int,
@fromoperatorid int

as
begin
declare @query nvarchar(4000)
declare @fromcountry2 varchar(10)
declare @fromoperatorid2 varchar(10)
set @fromcountry2 = CAST(@fromcountry as varchar(10))
set @fromcountry2 = isnull(@fromcountry2,0)
set @fromoperatorid2 = cast (@fromoperatorid as varchar(10))
set @fromoperatorid2 = isnull(@fromoperatorid2,0)
set @query = 'insert into sample1 (pname,rdatetime,fromcountry,fromoperatorid) values ('''+@pname+''','''+@rdatetime+''','''+@fromcountry2+''','''+@fromoperatorid2+''')'
print @query
end
```

or

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[proc_insertsample2]
@pname varchar(10),
@rdatetime varchar(10),
@fromcountry varchar(10),
@fromoperatorid varchar(10)

as
begin
declare @query nvarchar(4000)
set @fromcountry = ISNULL(@fromcountry,'')
set @fromoperatorid = ISNULL(@fromoperatorid,0)
set @query = 'insert into sample1 (pname,rdatetime,fromcountry,fromoperatorid) values ('''+@pname+''','''+@rdatetime+''','''+@fromcountry+''','''+@fromoperatorid+''')'
print @query
end
```

.I am modifing sp.Previously para was int ,changed to varchar.Can I set a value to input para.I don't want create  again variable to isnull result.I directly putted isnull in dynamic string which I am print and executing.But no use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but if you can define default values for parameters in a stored procedure by giving the parameters you want defaults for the default value:

```
@fromcountry VARCHAR(10) = ''
```

So your second sp would look like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[proc_insertsample](@pname VARCHAR(10) = '',
                                          @rdatetime VARCHAR(10) = '',
                                          @fromcountry VARCHAR(10) = '',
                                          @fromoperatorid VARCHAR(10) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @query = 'INSERT INTO sample1 (pname,rdatetime,fromcountry,fromoperatorid) VALUES ('''+@pname+''','''+@rdatetime+''','''+@fromcountry+''','''+@fromoperatorid+''')'
    PRINT @query
END
```

If you called `proc_insertsample1` with no parameters, your `@query` variable would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO sample1 (pname,rdatetime,fromcountry,fromoperatorid)
VALUES ('', '', '', '', '')
```

Alternatively, you could put the ISNULL check right in the dynamic SQL:

```
SET @query = 'INSERT INTO sample1 (pname,rdatetime,fromcountry,fromoperatorid) VALUES (''' + @pname + ''',''' + @rdatetime + ''',''' + ISNULL(@fromcountry,'') + ''',''' + ISNULL(@fromoperatorid,'') + ''')'
```

In which case your `@query` variable will (assuming you have 'John' for pname and '10/01/2007' for rdatetime) look like this:

```
INSERT INTO sample1 (pname,rdatetime,fromcountry,fromoperatorid)
VALUES ('John','10/01/2007','','')
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to deal with data integrity issues is to put DEFAULT and NOT NULL constraints on the fields in the table you're inserting. That way you move the validation logic from the stored procedure into the table itself.

It will also help you build a robust database design in the future.

Giving you a real life example, what you do is to check in your pocket every single time you insert a coin in a parking meter that is the right sized coin and waste time, instead of just making the coin slot in the parking meter small enough to only accept certain coin sizes and reject UNKNOWN coins.